# How to Install Android Emulator (emulator) SDK Tool Offline

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

I am currently trying to install the Android emulator in the android studio on ubuntu 19 now it keeps giving me this error

Packages to install:

```
- Android Emulator (emulator)

Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 29.0.11)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-5598178.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux-5598178.zip': Tag mismatch!
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 29.0.11)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Android Emulator (emulator)
```

is there a way I can install it offline cause I tried downloading the zip file and extracting it to `Android/Sdk`folder but its not been recognized as installed by android studio.

Comment: https://blog.sudobits.com/2014/07/28/getting-started-with-android-studio-on-ubuntu-linux-1404-lts/